# What is the growth rate of $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 + 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $a_1 = 1$, and let $a_{n+1} = \left(a_n\right)^2 + 1$.  What is the growth rate of $a_n$?  Even better, is there a closed-form formula for $a_n$?

Since each step is "basically squared", I'd expect it to grow something like $2^{2^{n-1}}$.  In fact, I'm pretty sure we have $2^{2^{n-2}} \leq a_n \leq 2^{2^{n-1}}$.

Do either of the ratios

$$
\frac{a_n}{2^{2^{n-2}}}
$$

or

$$
\frac{a_n}{2^{2^{n-1}}}
$$

converge to a nonzero value as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003095 gives an asymptotic formula of $c^{2^n}$ for $c \approx 1.2259$

Comment: The observation $2^{2^{n-1}}\le a_n\le 2^{2^n}$ seems incorrect. Consider, for example, $n=2$.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Thanks, you're correct; I had my indices off by 1.  I've corrected the question.

Comment: One observation: The sequence $$b_n:=\frac{a_n}{2^{2^{n-1}}}$$ satisfies the recursion $$b_{n+1}=b_n^2+c_n$$ where $c_n=2^{-2^n}$ and we have $b_1=1/2$. I was hoping that $b_n$ would be a decreasing sequence and since it is lower bounded by $0$, it would converge. Then from the recursion the limit would follow to be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sequence $b_n$ constructed in the comments, it is not difficult to see  that $0\le b_n\le 1/2$ (We can use induction to prove the second inequality and the first one is obvious).

Then, by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem there is a subsequence which converges. Let $\{b_{n_k}\}$ be such a subsequence. Let the limit be denoted by $b$. Then the recursion relation shows that $b$ should satisfy $b^2=b\implies b=0,1$. Since $b_n\le 1/2,\ b=0$.

Choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon<1/2$. Then, $\exists K, N$ such that $b_{n_k}<\epsilon\ \forall k\ge K$ and $c_n<\epsilon/2\ \forall n\ge N$. Let $N_1=\max(n_K,N)$ and let $K_1$ be such that $n_{K_1}\ge N_1$. Then, $b_{n_{K_1}+1}<\epsilon^2+\epsilon/2<\epsilon$ since $\epsilon<1/2$. Applying this logic further to $n\ge n_{K_1}+1$ shows that $b_{n}<\epsilon\ \forall n\ge n_{K_1}$. Hence $\forall \epsilon<1/2$, $\exists N$ such that $b_{n}<\epsilon\ \forall n\ge N$. Since this is true for all $0<\epsilon<1/2$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=0$.